# problem in running ngx-admin dashboard for angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install, ngx-admin

i have problems below when installing node modules.pls help
Angular CLI: 13.3.0
Node: 16.14.2
[here is list of problems](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues/5927)

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Do you try to install others packages with npm? I think it's an issue about your proxy (maybe company proxy)

Comment: no i just clone repository and run npm i

Comment: Could you try with an other package and tell me if you have the same issue?

Comment: i dont have any problem when i run ng new myApp in this case everything will install properly i just got errors for ngx-admin panel.i also tried metronic admin panel i got same errors i really confused

Comment: Are you connected with a company WiFi?

Comment: no i use my mobile internet by hotspot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243225/discussion-between-pterrat-and-reza-setareh).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like the package need node 14, and your machine is on node 16.

I suggest to install nvm: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm, which will allow you to switch between node versions easily.

Then use in a terminal

`$ nvm install 14`
`$ nvm use 14`
`$ npm install`

And it'll work